# Database created in XP to be opened on Vista

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in SQL server which is created on xp and to be opened on vista
When i try opening it on Vista.
Would this be possible

Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is no reason why this should not work.

Comment: It is not recognizing the .mdf

Comment: @user575219 - "It is not recognizing the .mdf" - could there, perhaps, be a useful error message that you haven't told us about yet?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server creates files that SQL Server can read. The file formats are independent of Windows versions.

What you should be aware of/considering are SQL Server versions and editions.

For instance, if you create a DB using SQL Server 2008 R2, you will not be able to attach/restore such a database using SQL Server 2005 or 2008, no matter what OS you're working on.

Similarly, if you've applied a particular service pack to the installation where the .mdf originates, you need to be working at the same or later service pack on the system where you want to read the file.

Similarly, if you create a database that *uses* features that are only available in higher level editions of SQL Server - i.e. something only available in Enterprise/Developer edition - you may have issues using the same database on a Standard Edition installation.

Comment: Ok I think thats the problem. I created it using SQL Server R2 but now needs to be opened in SQl server 2008

Comment: @user575219 - can't be done. newer versions of SQL Server can read and upgrade older files, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You don't open a sql server database with "xp" or "vista".  You open the database in *Sql Server*. That's all that matters here: does the machine have the correct version of Sql Server available?  Note that *no* version of Windows ships with Sql Server installed by default.

Also, unless you're talking about Sql Server Compact Edition you might want to re-think this.  Full editions of Sql Server belong on the *server* editions of Windows.  If you're building a database for an app that will live on individual user's desktop and the database will only serve the instance of the app on the machine, *do not use sql server for that database*.  Instead, use something like Sql Server Compact Edition (it uses a different engine than full sql server that is more desktop-friendly), SQLite, or even Access.

Comment: What is wrong with using Developer Edition, Evaluation Edition or Express Edition on a workstation? How do you know the OP is doing anything that is only serviced locally, rather than developing something locally that will be deployed later? If nothing else, you're writing consistent code instead of having to refactor everything when you switch or migrate. Not sure what Access, SQLite or SQL CE gain you when you have different behaviors (usually for the worse).

Comment: @Aaron - there's nothing wrong with using those editions for development of a db that will be deployed to a server.  But he's talking about installing the db to a new vista machine. That could mean a new dev box, but more likely it indicates deployment to me, most likely for a db that will "only be serviced locally."  IMO, that's just not a good idea.  Don't use server editions of sql server for that -- not even express edition. This is exactly what desktop in-process class databases are for.

Comment: I think you're making assumptions about his purpose, and I still don't think anyone needs to use some other platform for local work, especially if they're learning the platform. They male Express/Developer editions for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

As @Demian said, you can not open database created in SQL Server 2008 R2 in SQL Server 2008. But alternatively if you are sure that your database is not using any features specific to R2, you can script out whole database and then create similar database by running those scripts into SQL Server 2008 (ofcourse with some changes in script). And then just write some insert scripts to import data from 2008R2 to 2008 (Or you can use SSIS to dump data from one location to another location)

I think the question itself is pretty unclear. No explaination of environment of both XP and Vista machines (e.g. DBMS versions including SPs) or how you are trying to open/access database (using attach or by restoring backup). Without proper information I don't think there is any EXACT solution.